# Executing javascript function in ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview, scheduledexecutorservice

I've got a loop establish using a ScheduledExecutorService that runs every 1 second. I have a WebView (JavaFX) that i want to call a function from it.

I can call functions fine if I put it it a button like:

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    webEngine.executeScript("someFunction();");
});
```

and click on it and it execute just fine, but when i do:

```
execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
    loop();
    webEngine.executeScript("someFunction();");
}, 3000L, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

the program just stops at `webEngine.executeScript("someFunction();");` (does the same if i put that line inside my `loop()` method)

How can I execute `someFunction()`every second alongside the rest of my program? Why is it pausing?

Comment: What do you mean by "just stops"? Freezes/hangs? Crashes? If so, what does the stack trace say?

Comment: @Mena I can still click stuff and do stuff, nothing appears in the console, everything works fine except that whatever should be executing in scheduleexecutorservice just doesn't, eg. if i put a `System.out.println("bleh")` after the `webEngine.executeScript("someFunction();")` it doesn't reach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this:

```
timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new WebViewProcess(), 3000, 1000);

private class WebViewProcess extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    webEngine.executeScript("someFunction();");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: Note that `Timer` is deprecated and `ScheduledExecutorService` is the recommended replacement. Likely the resolution here is on the `Platform.runLater` async invocation.

Comment: @Mena yes, that was the part that i used and got working :)